# how does android understand which home screen is being viewed by the user?

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget

I wanted to understand how does the Android OS figure out which home screen the user is viewing currently and render the appropriate icons and widgets on that screen based on the user's left or right swipe on the touch screen of the device.

The OS must save a state of the screen and IDs or something relative to the objects placed on the screen to retrieve the state each time the screen becomes visible.

From my research I understand that Android OS treats all the 7-8 homescreens on devices as one single host.

Also my question might seem vague, but the reason why I am asking is because it seems reasonable that app widgets on android devices, update not only when the phone is awake but also only when the app widget itself is visible. I know that Google has declined the enhancement request by many others but I don't think that is good enough. Link [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6393).

That is the reason why I am trying to give it a shot to understand and implement it for my app with whatever Android knows about the state of the home screens.

Any help or insight is much appreciated. Also the experts out there let me know if you think this can be even implemented for one off apps at all?

Comment: ...ANDROID doesn't know the state of the homescreens. The Launcher app does. Or any of the many other home replacement apps. --And there's your reason why there isn't a standard way to do what you want- because there isn't a standard Launcher app.

Comment: Related to (not duplicate of) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086040/get-number-of-home-screens-in-android @Jon I answered pretty much the same 5 days ago :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, as the link you posted clearly states, there's no way to know.

Also, if you consider the fact that "Home" is just an application like all the others, it makes even less sense to have a unified API for that. A lot of people use Launcher Pro or similar applications, which would probably not implement it.